# jQuery Hide Options of a Dropdown as per Array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have  an array of `types` as below and am trying to enable only the options of Dropdown which are present in `types`array

```
var types = ["LEDES 1998B", "LEDES 1998B-INTL"]
```

On the UI I need to see only 'LEDES 1998B', 'LEDES 1998B-INTL' in the dropdown which are in `types` and other options have to be hidden

```
<select id="FormatType" name="instance_FormatType.id" data-name="Format Type">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>      
    <option value="1">
        LEDES 1998B
    </option>       
    <option value="2">
        LEDES 1998B-INTL
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        LEDES 98BI
    </option>       
    <option value="4">
        Summary
    </option>
```

Could someone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your array is in a valid format, you can use `filter` to check the options. Try this:

```
var types = ["LEDES 1998B", "LEDES 1998B-INTL"];
$('#FormatType option:not(:first)').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), types) == -1;
}).remove(); // or possibly hide() depending on your need/browser support
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/67ehxs6f/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate It. I also need to show "-- Select --" as selected and it has to be very first option always. How do I do this?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I need to get the element by name since id changes for each user so I tried doing it with name field instead of id http://jsfiddle.net/xeqrkrao/1/ but it isn't working as expected

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS version:

```
var select = document.getElementById('request5900-instance_qiFormatType');
var types = ["LEDES 1998B", "LEDES 1998B-INTL"];

for( var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++ ){
    var label = select.options[i].innerHTML.trim();
    if( types.indexOf( label ) < 0 ){
        select.removeChild( select.options[i] );
        // need to decrement because indexes change after node removal
        i--;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xsyab5kt/

Comment: Thanks for including a vanilla JS. It's nice to see.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "option" ).each(function( index ) {
      if(jQuery.inArray(($( this ).text()), types)!==-1) {
        $("option[value=" + ($(this).attr('val')) + "]").hide();
        } 
});
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide them, can either remove or disable

Can disable it by following, example disable option with value 3

```
$("#request5900-instance_qiFormatType>option[value='3']").attr('disabled', true);
```